# android device not showing up on clicking run

Tags: android, device, android-install-apk, run-configuration

I have LG optimus Black.

 I have the following settings:

> 1. USB debugging on.
> 2. Unknown applications checked.
> 3. Driver installed.
> 4. The app is deployed on Android 2.1 an the phone has Android 2.2. So no problems there I guess.

In fact, it was working fine till some time ago. 

 But its not showing up now. Any ideas why? Thank you.

Comment: your OS ? On any other computer does it appear ?

Comment: I am using windows 7. All the systems in my office use the same OS. So I guess its pointless to try on them. Also it was working some time ago. I dont know why it'd suddenly stop working though

Comment: it'S not pointless, please try

Comment: ok. I just tried on my friend's system. Its not working. :( Btw, I closed and restarted eclipse. Not working either. :(

Comment: youre connected as charge only?

Comment: Did you try restarting adb? Run `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` from the command line (the `adb` command resides in your `ANDROID-SDK/platform-tools/` directory).

Comment: I dont know. How do I check. My usb debuggin is on

Comment: on the phone pull down the notification bar while connected to the phone. select to change the usb connection type to "charge only"

Comment: @alextsc I did it. Not working :(

Comment: @B Young Its not on charge only. Its connected din debugging mode

Comment: Those are two different things: http://thinktutorial.com/smartphones/android/change-usb-connection-type/

Comment: I dont have that option. I reinstalled the driver. That did the trick though

Comment: hmm weird. well glad it works

Comment: @Brahadeesh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2675/discussion-between-b-young-and-brahadeesh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling the driver. Worked for me.